# To find the updated data between current and previous data in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

Data will be updated in Neo4j and I have no clue on what is updated and when is updated. My task is to have a scheduler that picks the data and update the same in Seibel. is there any way to find the delta in neo4j DB so that the updated nodes and relationships can be updated in siebel.

Can anyone suggest any possible ways. There will not be any timestamp on the nodes and relatiosnhips.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to the transaction events and build your own log of nodes and rels that are interesting to your update? http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. But in our req. we will not know what data is updated and when they are updated. We will have only the data.